# Accessing the raw data of an audio track in a video asset for real time processing

Tags: ios, avfoundation, core-audio, avplayer

I am trying to intercept in real time the audio stream of a file-based video asset in order to apply some live effects to the sound track and mix it with other audio sources while the video is playing.

Ideally, it would be great to be able to take the audio track of an AVPlayer object, insert it into an audio Graph as a separately addressable input, process it through a callback with suitable Audio Units, and then re-inject it in real time for delivery to the audio output, but I can't find an easy method to do it while maintaining the integrity of the original video asset. I have been unable to find out how to access the audio buffer of an AVPlayer in order to forward its raw data to a sound processing callback.

It seems to me that the only suitable approach would consist in splitting out the audio and video tracks by handling them as separate files, and then processing the video track (with the sound removed) with an AVPlayer and having all the audio run through a separate Core Audio processing path running in parallel, but I'm afraid this approach would make A-V synchronization challenging, in addition to adding a cumbersome offline preparation task. Any idea or alternative approach?

Answer (score 0):

I think AVAudioPlayer is not real-time capable and it is not possible to connect directly this high level framework with the lowest level Audio Units (and audio graph).

I would suggest to implement a file player node in the audio graph. This player node shall play the audio from the video. But maybe the new [AVAudioEngine](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioEngine_Class/index.html) is good approach, but this framework is very buggy and not well documented at the moment - its beta. 
Audio signal real-time processing is a tough topic for its own - combined with video it is really hard. :-) Please let me know if you found a feasible solution for your application.